# Python: How to make DataFrame from a list of dictionary that contains list as value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib

I want to make a Python DataFrame that looks like this :

[image: Desired dataframe shape]

from this data structure:

```
list_reports = 
[
    {'Instagram': [{'yosuahanjaya': 3260, 'last_update':'09-2020'}]}, 
    {'Twitter': [{'yosuahanjaya': 850, 'last_update':'09-2020'}]}, 
    {'Instagram': [{'yosuahanjayayt': 462, 'last_update':'09-2020'}]}, 
    {'Twitter': [{'yosuahanjayayt': 1900, 'last_update':'09-2020'}]}
]
```

This is my current DataFrame structure, the code is shown below:

```
    list_dataframe = [] # populate list of df

    for dict in list_reports:
        for key, values in dict.items():
            df = pd.DataFrame(values)
            list_dataframe.append(df)

    # combine dataframe
    indexed_df = [df.set_index('last_update') for df in list_dataframe]
    final_df = pd.concat(indexed_df, axis=1)  # type = dataframe
    final_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    return final_df
```

[image: Dataframe result]

Does anyone know how to make the desired DataFrame out of the data structure? What should I modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want to change the formation of `report`, then this code should create the desired DataFrame:

```py
for dictionary in report:
    social_network = list(dictionary.keys())[0]
    dict_of_user = list(dictionary.values())[0][0]
    username = [key for key in dict_of_user.keys() if key != 'last_update'][0]

    if username not in indexes:
        indexes.append(username)

    if social_network not in data.keys():
        data[social_network] = [dict_of_user[username]]
    else:
        data[social_network].append(dict_of_user[username])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, hope it helps

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( { "":["yosuahanjaya","yosuahanjayayt"],"Instagram":[3260,462],"Twitter":[850,1900], "last_update":['09-2020','09-2020'] } )
print(df)
```